# error with passenger +sailsjs + nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, sails.js, passenger

I'm using passenger to run nodejs application (sailsjs.org) but I have problem when I run it with nginx and passenger.

The application generate this error and I can't solve it.

```
[ 2016-11-11 13:27:30.3694 31423/7fdec5782700 age/Cor/Con/InternalUtils.cpp:112 ]: [Client 1-36] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
```

Please help me to find the problem.